# Azure Red Hat VM

Tags: linux, redhat, virtual-machines, azure

I see lots of stuff in the news about Red Hat partnering with MS Azure, and articles seem to indicate you can fire up a Red Hat VM on Azure now. But when I go to create a new VM, I can't find Red Hat anywhere.  What is the situation? How does one start a Red Hat VM in azure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the docs:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/campaigns/redhat/

> FAQ What solutions are available today? Today, customers can use Red
>   Hat Cloud Access to bring their subscriptions to Azure and run Red Hat
>   Enterprise Linux, Red Hat Enterprise Linux Atomic Host, Red Hat JBoss
>   Enterprise Application Server, Red Hat JBoss Enterprise Web Server,
>   Red Hat Gluster Storage, and OpenShift by Red Hat.

It's not just firing up a VM. You need a subscription from Red Hat Cloud Access:

http://www.redhat.com/en/technologies/cloud-computing/cloud-access

Answer (score 1):

at the moment you can go to VMDepot and fire up a trial but it's not live yet..
https://vmdepot.msopentech.com/List/Index?sort=Featured&search=redhat